# MySQL Connector does not install on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows

The installation of MySQL Connector (mysql-connector-net-6.9.8.msi) fails on my machine with message 'Setup Wizard ended permanently because of an error. Your system has not been modified'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have Windows 10 Pro 64 bit with VS2015 and the following .NET framework installed:

v2.0.50727  2.0.50727.4927  SP2
v3.0  3.0.30729.4926  SP2
v3.5  3.5.30729.4926  SP1
v4
  Client  4.6.01038
  Full  4.6.01038
v4.0
  Client  4.0.0.0

Comment: Look at/enable the installer logs; http://superuser.com/questions/180281/what-folder-are-installation-logs-in

Comment: The log file contains some fatal error messages, but I do not have an idea on what do they mean. see http://slogpost.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MySqlConnectorLog.txt (search 'error' in the text)

Comment: It installs fine on some other machine with Windows 10 32 bit (without VS2015).

Comment: It fails with error 1603 which is somewhat generic.  You seem to be installing from D: does it work if you run the msi from C:?

Comment: From C: it fails with the same result.